# Not moving to profile screen even after giving genuine credentials in login page

Tags: java, android

In database we have login details  `{"email":"nagu@gmail.com","pwd":"12345"}`.By using REST services I got the URL, I need to validate the credentials and move to next screen. But unable to move to next screen so please help me

```
public class LoginScreen extends DIBaseActivty {

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;

private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    editTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emaiId);
    editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

}

public void buttonLogin (View arg0)
{
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
    new TaskLogin().execute(username,password);
}

public class TaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\t Loading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RestSpring/DialysisInfo/login");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try{
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("username",params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("password",params[1]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception";
        }
        try{
            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(response_code==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line= reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return (result.toString());
            } else { return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,DIUserProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LoginScreen.this.finish();
        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my error log

```
                      02-02 10:42:56.660 25016-27263/com.dialysis 

W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    02-02 10:42:56.661 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:238)
    02-02 10:42:56.661 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
    02-02 10:42:56.661 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    02-02 10:42:56.663 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    02-02 10:42:56.663 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
    02-02 10:42:56.664 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
    02-02 10:42:56.664 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
    02-02 10:42:56.664 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
    02-02 10:42:56.665 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
    02-02 10:42:56.665 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
    02-02 10:42:56.665 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
    02-02 10:42:56.665 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.dialysis.renalteam.app.ui.activities.LoginScreen$TaskLogin.doInBackground(LoginScreen.java:86)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at com.dialysis.renalteam.app.ui.activities.LoginScreen$TaskLogin.doInBackground(LoginScreen.java:49)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-02 10:42:56.666 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    02-02 10:42:56.667 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    02-02 10:42:56.667 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
    02-02 10:42:56.667 25016-27263/com.dialysis W/System.err:   ... 20 more
    02-02 10:42:56.714 25016-25071/com.dialysis W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    02-02 10:42:56.714 25016-25071/com.dialysis W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43cbb00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    02-02 10:42:57.143 25016-25071/com.dialysis W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    02-02 10:42:57.144 25016-25071/com.dialysis W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43cbd20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    02-02 10:52:41.787 25016-25030/com.dialysis W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.515ms
```

Comment: It causes an excepion. Try to debug and find the point where it causes an exception

Comment: is your URL publicly accessible? or at first check your URL in your phone/emulator browser .

Comment: @Prag'sシ i'm new to android and unable to find exact exception, URL cannot accessible

Comment: Try to give you pc's ip address instead of `localhost`, if you are on same intranet

Comment: Its working with my pc's IP address in plugin

Comment: Pardon? a plugin?

Comment: i'm checking URL in Advance REST Client plugin in chrome

Comment: have you added permission of access_network_state in manifest ?

Comment: @Prag'sシ ya added

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni Things to notice : 1st you have to change your url from localhost to IP address. 2nd you must have connected to the local server. otherwise your device can not be connected to the local server url. Try to run it from emmulator and if you are using wifi, you have to use LAN wifi for running this service in your device.

Comment: same way i tried what you said but still i did not get the result..!! is it possible to come teamviewer to solve?

Answer (score 1):

From your logcat:

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Your Android app failed to connect to the server. Set debug breakpoints and check the following:

1. Url is correct
2. Method name is correct
3. Parameters key and value are correct
4. Server is working fine or not

Comment: Unable to find out where the exception is

Comment: From the URL (localhost/127.0.0.1).     i think you have hosted it in your pc(Think how can a mobile communicate with Data which is local to your computer). try hosting it live then check.

Comment: I'm using IP address instead of local host..!! what else you want me to change?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified you are connected to a server from the device or emulator so I guess you are using your application in the emulator.

If you are referring your localhost on your system from the Android emulator then you have to use http://10.0.2.2:8080/ Because Android emulator runs in a Virtual Machine therefore here 127.0.0.1 or localhost will be emulator's own loopback address.

Replace: url = http://localhost:8080/RestSpring/DialysisInfo/login"

With : url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/RestSpring/DialysisInfo/login"

Comment: Try to open 10.0.2.2:8080/RestSpring/DialysisInfo/login url from your machine if it's not working then there may be issue with your firewall let me know that if it's working with your pc.

Comment: nope... As per your instructions i tried in my machine..!! Its not working

Comment: So might be the problem with your IIS Server if you are using Windows so first thing is upload your WebService to IIS server and try to open from IIS server if it will work then you just need to use the same url in android.

Comment: I'm not aware of this iis server... can you help me how to use that one

Comment: In case if you are using .Net service then follow this link to deploy service on IIS http://programmerguru.com/webservice-tutorial/how-to-deploy-asp-dot-net-webservice-in-iis/

Comment: i'm Using REST Api

Comment: i'm using remote system from local system.. i should work in remote machine only

Comment: Okay and what about device are you using emulator or Genymotion or real device for testing?

Comment: Android Studio's AVD only

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15864222/6032850 and let me know if your problem is solved or not.

Comment: unable to get that what exactly they are saying..!! more over i dont have permission to use router and look in to that..!

Comment: Any other way we can make it?